# Explain Malware-finding function in bash

Tags: grep, malware

I've just spotted in `.bash_history` file lines below:

```
grep -iHlnr 'filesman' *2> /dev/null
grep -iHlnr 'eval.*base64_decode' *2> /dev/null
```

From Google I know that is something like 'malware finding command'. May somebody explain what does it exactly do? (Iknow what is grep for, but that syntax isn't clear to me).

Comment: [explainshell](http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=grep+-iHlnr+%27filesman%27+*2%3E+%2Fdev%2Fnull) does a decent job of it...

Comment: `-n` is useless in `lnr`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The commands you posted do nothing useful — they run `grep` on files whose name ends with `2`, and recursively in directories whose name ends with `2`. There's a missing space after `*` (the space after `>` is permitted but not useful and more confusing than anything):

```
grep -iHlnr 'filesman' * 2>/dev/null
grep -iHlnr 'eval.*base64_decode' * 2>/dev/null
```

This searches for files containing `filesman`, or containing `eval` followed by `base64_decode` on the same line, in the current directory and its subdirectories recursively. The search is case-insensitive. Look at the manual of grep for the exact meaning of each option.

Calling that “malware finding” is a gross exaggeration. It's probably looking for PHP malware, but it might return some legitimate files as well and it only finds a few specific malwares.

Comment: We could also point out that `.` should be preferable over `*` to also search in files whose name starts with `.` in the current directory (and avoid problems with file names starting with `-`), and that `-H` and `-n` are redundant with `-l`.